# Regarding Oracle Stored Procedure not compiling because table does not currently exist

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle10g

All,

I have the following Package Description:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ashish.PKG_Customer AUTHID CURRENT_USER AS
  TYPE cursorType IS REF CURSOR;

  PROCEDURE CreateCustomerTable;
  PROCEDURE SelectCustomers(o_ResultSet OUT cursorType);    
END PKG_Customer;
```

and here is the package body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY ashish.PKG_Customer AS

  PROCEDURE CreateCustomerTable AS
    sQuery VARCHAR2(1000);
  BEGIN
    sQuery := 'CREATE TABLE tblCustomer2(
               CustomerID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
               FirstName VARCHAR2(50),
               LastName VARCHAR2(50),
               City VARCHAR2(200), 
               State_Province VARCHAR2(100),
               PostalCode VARCHAR2(25)
              )';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sQuery;
  END CreateCustomerTable;

  PROCEDURE SelectCustomers(o_ResultSet OUT cursorType) AS
  BEGIN
    OPEN o_ResultSet FOR
      SELECT CustomerID,
             FirstName,
             LastName,
             City,
             State_Province,
             PostalCode
        FROM tblCustomer;
  END SelectCustomers;
END PKG_Customer;
```

The issue I am facing is that my package will not compile because the table does not currently exist. Surely I should be able to create stored procedures in advance for tables that currently don't exist in Oracle right? Am I doing something wrong here?

The server version is Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit.

Thanks!
-Ashish

Comment: In the past when I have posted a question where folks thought the question needed to be edited for some reason, I was asked the opposite question: Why isn't this community wiki? So since then I just check community wiki on all my questions. I would love to know when a question should or should not be community wiki.

Comment: As far as I understand wiki is good place for questions that don't have "silver bullet" answer (programming style, best practices, personal preferences, first program you wrote etc. topics where discussion can go on and on - never reaching conclusion that can truly be an "accepted" solution to a problem).

Comment: Thanks @eyescream. I'll be more careful in distinguishing when I should and should not have the community wiki option checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of. How can you compile something against objects that don't exist? Oracle doesn't know if you've mistyped the table name trying to reference an existing table or are hoping to create the table at a later time.

Why not create your tables first then create/compile your packages?

Comment: I am trying to port inline SQL for an internal tool into Oracle stored procedures. The tool creates a lot of tables as it transforms the data & performs calculations. So there will be a lot of stored procedures that are just creating tables and a few that will be retrieving data from those tables. The expectation that the tables used by stored procedures exist before creating the stored procedures seems a little limiting no?

Comment: I guess you could argue that it is limiting but at the same time the idea of compiling is to check syntax and ensure things will work as written.

One way, which I don't recommend, to get around this is to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. For example:
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT x, y FROM table_which_is_hopefully_here WHERE blah = ?' USING myBlahVariable;

Without knowing your exact usecase would temporary tables help?

Comment: For some of the intermediate tables, I was going to use GLOBAL TEMPORARY tables anyways but I feel this situation almost necessitates it. It seems that I would have to go that route & create empty shells for tables that I want to persist. Thanks!

Comment: Generally speaking, you should not be creating and dropping tables within PL/SQL. Oracle works better with constant data structures (and appropriately gathered statistics).

Answer (score 1):

You can create the package in advance (meaning it will exist as an object in the database), but it will be marked invalid by Oracle.  Oracle will attempt to recompile the object the first time it is referenced so if your tables exist at that time it will be OK.

However, you can run into problems when the dependencies are more than one level deep - Oracle will not reach down into the dependency chain to recompile all necessary invalid objects, and discarding the state of a package through recompilation can can cause a problem if the previous state was in use by another package.

Comment: @dpbradley & @redcayuga: Definitely seems a limiting pre-requisite. I was going to say that SQL Server allows stored procedure to be compiled without the tables existing but I am not so sure that is the case. Is there a way I can programatically ask the packages to be recompiled?

Comment: @tundal45 - you can programatically recomple with an "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE..." of the standard compile statement, but obviously not from the package itself.  Creating tables within packages isn't a usual practice with Oracle for many reasons that are probably outside the scope of this question.

Comment: @dpbradley - So what I would be doing most is more of a CREATE TABLE AS SELECT FROM" type of statements which I feel are closer to CREATE TABLE than are to INSERT/UPDATE, etc. The idea behind having it in stored procedure is mostly to get rid of Inline SQL in the VB.NET app that interacts with the database. Is there another option outside of stored procedure for this kind of situation that you can recommend? Thanks again for your valuable time & input.

Answer (score 0):

All referenced objects, including tables and views, must exists when the package is compiled. If the table is altered or dropped the package will become invalid and will have to be recompiled. So create the table in the ashish schema first.

This is even true for "AUTHID CURRENT_USER" packages. It's a funny situation because when a procedure in the package is run the procedure will look for the table in the invoker's schema, not the package owner schema so the table may not exist in that schema and Oracle will raise a runtime exception. But the owner of the package can compile it because the table exists in its schema. It's funny but that's the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can code your sql into a string (dynamic) and then pass it to an execute statement.   I'm sure this way, oracle won't know what you're going to run before hand.